# Python combo list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm trying to build a name, surname combos from a list. But failed to do this in my loop function. Appreciate some help.

```
names = ['Appleby', 'Damien','James']
nn = ['James', 'Jim', 'Jimmy', 'Jimmie', 'Jamie', 'Jem']
idx = 2
combos = [[names[0], n] for n in nn]
```

the results:

```
[['Appleby', 'James'],
 ['Appleby', 'Jim'],
 ['Appleby', 'Jimmy'],
 ['Appleby', 'Jimmie'],
 ['Appleby', 'Jamie'],
 ['Appleby', 'Jem']]
```

What I would like to achieve is :

```
[['Appleby', 'Damien' , 'James'],
 ['Appleby', 'Damien' ,'Jim'],
 ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'Jimmy'],
 ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'Jimmie'],
 ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'Jamie'],
 ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'Jem']]
```

where the combos happens only on the pre-defined index, in this case, idx = 2

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using `idx` anywhere. So that's just signifying which name in the first list is being replaced by names in the second list?

Try this list comprehension:

```
[[n2 if iname == idx else n1 for iname, n1 in enumerate(names)] for n2 in nn]
```

Comment: @girlrilaz by which I mean that it works even when the index is 1 and the list length is still 2. Try it

Comment: This is also O(n**2) whereas I offered an O(n) solution.

Comment: Your solution is also is the same O as mine

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind something that isn't squeezed into a single line? You can try this.

```
def pholdercombo(lst1, index, lst2):

    if index < 0 or len(lst1) < (index - 1):
        raise ValueError('index not valid for input list')

    for s in lst2:
        cpy = list(lst1)
        cpy[index] = s
        yield cpy


names = ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'James']
nn = ['James', 'Jim', 'Jimmy', 'Jimmie', 'Jamie', 'Jem']

# throws if string not present.
idx = names.index('James')

print(list(pholdercombo(names, idx, nn)))
```

result:

```
[['Appleby', 'Damien', 'James'], 
 ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'Jim'], 
 ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'Jimmy'], 
 ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'Jimmie'], 
 ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'Jamie'], 
 ['Appleby', 'Damien', 'Jem']]
```

It technically returns a generator, but it could be easily converted to list, alternatively iterate it or just call `list` on the result like I did.

It just loops over the combo list and returns the elements with the element at the required index changed.

You can rearrange the list or change which index it swaps on and all should be rosy.

Answer (score -1):

You’re only making a list of the first item in `names` and the name in `nn`. So with `idx` being where in `names` to replace slice `names` using `idx` and insert each name into it.

```
[[*names[:idx], n, *names[idx+1:]] for n in nn]
```

This will ensure that the name is replaced at `idx` if you want the new name always at the end then either take the above and `n` to the end or use:

```
no_first = names[:]; del no_first[idx]
[no_first+[n] for n in nn])
```

Comment: @Jab while you are technically correct that it produces the output stated in the question, OP is pointing out that it does not produce the output they expect then `idx == 1` (e.g. if the list is`['Appleby', 'James', 'Damien']`)

Comment: Edited, I guess I misunderstood OP. Although now this should be what OP intends.